# Massive pulley, torque and tension

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction, torque, string

Given a pulley and two masses, like so:

[image]

Take the pulley to have a non negligible mass, zero friction between pulley and axle, but enough friction between pulley and rope such that the rope doesn't slip. The center of mass of the pulley is stationary.

Now, apparently, it is the case that the torque on the pulley is equal to the difference in tensions from both sides times the radius. Why is that?

I'm not sure if this should be obvious, but it isn't to me. As I understand it, the cause of the rotation is friction between the pulley and rope, and tension only transmits forces axially. If there was no friction, the pulley would not rotate, and the rope would simply slide. Is there any physical or mathematical arguments for the relation between the friction and the tension(s)?

Comment: I have already drawn one, and even looked for the answer. But people simply state that this is case. The definition that was I given of tension force is that it is simply a means of transmission of force between m1 and m2... maybe there's something wrong with this definition?

Comment: A force is a force, not a "means". I have no idea what a "means" is, physically speaking.

Comment: Ok. I agree with that. We can also think about the rope as being constructed out of a great number of harmonic oscillators, right? This is clear to me. But how do we go from this "1D" view to the view in which the rope acts on something that is side by side with it (the pulley)?

Answer (score 0):

It is not the friction where the losses go.

The friction is only there so that the pulley spins as the rope accelerates.  Because the pulley accelerates and has non-negligible mass, there is a [torque required to accelerate the pulley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_acceleration), the equation is $$\tau = I \alpha$$ where $\tau$ is torque, $I$ is the mass moment of inertia and $\alpha$ is angular acceleration.

Comment: I understand that. But why is the torque also  equal to the difference in tensions in both sides?

Comment: @alansammarone The force of the rope creates a torque.  $\tau = F\times r$.  It's not equal to the torque, it's equal to the force the creates the torque.

Comment: My question is why the F  that we should use in the torque formula is Tension1 - Tension2, and not force of friction, since friction is the interaction between the pulley and rope that causes rotation.

Comment: @alansammarone The friction is the difference.  It is how the rope is able to make the pulley move.  Without friction the rope would move and the pulley wouldn't.  Since the pulley has mass, the friction takes away from the tension as it acts over the pulley.